# XML::Parser print single attribute value

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I'm parsing a XML file and the file has nodes like this.

```
<product id="12345" model="dvd" section="cmp" img="junk.jpg"></product>
```

Here is my code. I need to print the value of `id` attribute for all products.

```
use XML::Parser;
my $parser = XML::Parser->new( Handlers => { Start => \&handle_start } );
$parser->parsefile('D:\Project\mob.xml');

sub handle_start {
    my ( $expat, $element, %attrs ) = @_;
    if ( $element eq 'product' ) {
        print $element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the `id` in the `%attrs` hash, you just need to print it:

```
sub handle_start {
    my ( $expat, $element, %attrs ) = @_;
    if ( $element eq 'product' ) {
        print $attrs{id}, "\n";
    }
}
```

`XML::Parser` is a low-level parser.  If you would consider using one with a more sophisticated API, try [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3A%3ATwig):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = <<XML;
<product id="12345" model="dvd" section="cmp" img="junk.jpg"></product>
XML

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => { product => sub { print $_->att('id'), "\n" } },
);
$twig->parse($xml);
```

Comment: XML::LibXML: `say $_->value for $doc->findnodes('//product/@id');`